# Integer partitions using generating functions

Tags: number-theory, generating-functions, integer-partitions

For each natural number $ n $ we consider the equation
$$x_{1}+2x_{2}+\dots+nx_{n}=n$$
Where $x_{1},\dots,x_{n}$ are nonnegative integers. Prove that this equation  has the same number of solutions that satisfy condition 1 as solutions that satisfy condition 2.

1. For each $k\in\{1,2,\dots,n-1\}$, $x_{k} >0$ or $x_{k+1}=0$
2. For each $k\in\{1,2,\dots,n-1,n\}$, $x_{k}=0$ or $x_{k}=1$

I proved this using Ferrers diagram and showing bijection, however, I'm curious if this can be solved by the method of generating functions. Thanks in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a start.  The generating function for the partitions that satisfy condition 2 (also known as partitions into distinct parts) is
$\prod_{k=1}^\infty (1+z^k)$.

For condition 1, conditioning on the largest part $k$ yields generating function
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \prod_{i=1}^k \left(z^i + z^{2i} + z^{3i} + \cdots \right)
=
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \prod_{i=1}^k \frac{z^i}{1-z^i}.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the check mark, but it remains to show that those two generating functions are equal.